# React Native Navigator Unexpected Token

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to switch between scenes and tested that `<{Some imported Scene} />` works perfectly but the following codes doesn't. 
I am very new to React-Native, The error that I got is Unexpected Token at line 30 of `index.android.js`, which is the line that saids `this.(scene[route.name] || scene['LoginView']);`

> index.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

import LoginView from './Scence-Android/LoginView';
import SettingView from './Scence-Android/SettingView';

class TrackrModule extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Navigator
          initialRoute={{ name: 'LoginView' }}
          renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
            var scene = {
              "LoginView": () => {
                return (<LoginView navigator={navigator} title="Login" />)
              },
              "SettingView": () => {
                return (<SettingView navigator={navigator} title="Setting" />)
              }
            }
            this.(scene[route.name] || scene['LoginView']);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> LoginView

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

export default class LoginView extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }
  btnLogin_pressed(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name:"SettingView"
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
          <TextInput>
            placeholder="Username"
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChange={(event) => this.setState({username: event.nativeEvent.text})}
            value={this.state.username}
          </TextInput>

          <TextInput>
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry = { true }
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChange={(event) => this.setState({password: event.nativeEvent.text})}
            value={this.state.password}/>
          </TextInput>

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.btnLogin_pressed.bind(this)}>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot you a () operator after this in javascript. So `this.(scene[route.name] || scene['LoginView']);` gives you an error.

Also you need to return a component from the renderScene method. So the following code will be more appropriate than `this.(scene[route.name] || scene['LoginView']);`:

`return (scene[route.name] || scene['LoginView']);`

Comment: maybe `return (scene[route.name || 'LoginView'])` ?

Comment: I think scene is a object with name of the route as key and component as value. so `return (scene[route.name] || scene['LoginView']);` should be correct. @stereodenis

Comment: Thanks @AakashSigdel and stereodenis, that was one drunk coding :)